# Trigger a binding update in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

My XAML set up is a bit complex code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:SuperCoolObject x:Key="firstObject"/>
    <local:TotallyHotObject x:Key="secondObject"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems, Source={StaticResource firstObject}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <lol:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"  Equals="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource secondObject}}" />
                    <Style x:Key="On" TargetType="local:ThemedImage">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
    </ItemsControl>                 
</Grid>
```

(I've omitted the actual DataTemplate)

Notice how the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsSource` binds to `firstObject` and `myConverter` binds to `secondObject`. What I need to do is have the `ItemsSource` binding refresh when the `myConverter` binding (`secondObject.SelectedItem`) property changes.

All the appropriate properties are set up as binding properties but I need some way or forcing `ItemsSource` to refresh in XAML.

Comment: Is secondObject binded to ItemSource of some other ItemsControl?

Comment: Nope, secondObject is actually a ListView.